# Strip out referers from script src

Tags: html, http-referer, script-tag, referrer-policy

I'm doing a remote script-src

```
<script src="http://thirdparty.com/test.js"></script>
```

I don't want to send my http referer headers to thirdparty.com. How do I do it?

Comment: Serve the script yourself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would have to proxy the request for the script through your own server. For example:

```
<script src="stripreferrer.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fthirdparty.com%2Ftest.js"></script>
```

Then, your server-side code would make the HTTP request sans referrer code, and pass the response to the client.

Comment: Or use @Bergi's suggestion if serving a copy of the third-party script is OK.

Answer (score 13):

The answers from 2013 are obsolete: you can do it by setting a [referrer policy](https://www.w3.org/TR/referrer-policy/) on your webpage. For example, if you have

`<meta name="referrer" content="origin">`

on your page, then any `<script src="...">` resources fetched from that page (after that line) will send only the origin and not the full URL. Other options include "no-referrer".

See http://caniuse.com/#feat=referrer-policy for status of adoption by browsers: as of Sep 2016 it's supported by most major non-IE browsers. This [older blog post](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2015/01/21/meta-referrer/) on the Mozilla Security blog may be worth reading if you prefer not to read the standard.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the HTTP protocol. You cannot control this using HTML or JavaScript.